# Character set fuss after migrating from Windows 10 to Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, rsync

I've migrated from Windows 10 to Kubuntu in August.

Since then, data backup is a persistent problem. Sometimes it works, then files with special characters (german Umlaute ä ö ü ) make problems.

I wouldn't mind if these characters are not properly displayed. But sometimes my system can't read the files anymore. Data synchronisation with rsync sometomes works and sometimes not - for the same drives.

I've spent days now and I think I understand the basic things about character sets.

What I've noticed now is that dolphin (the file explorer) displays the same file sometimes in one or the other character set. E.g. a file with a "Ü" was displayed later (without reboot) as "Ã" for example.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Do you have the language support installed? I mean German, of course.

Comment: The system language is german, I suppose you mean that.

I set the character set on utf-8 again and most of the things work. 
There is sometimes singular files which the system can't read. I have to rename them in Windows then. 

Is it possible to temporarely change the character set to 8859-1 or to access a file in a file explorer as a 8859-1 file?

Comment: Hello? Nobody can help? I couldn't find a similar topic in the forum.